# Linq : Comparing 1 Child Collection to (Aggregated) ChildCollection(s)

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Linq question: (DotNet Framework 4.0)

I have the following classes:

```
public class Employee
{
    public Guid? EmployeeUUID { get; set; }
    public string SSN { get; set; }
}

public class JobTitle
{
    public Guid? JobTitleSurrogateKey { get; set; }
    public string JobTitleName { get; set; }
}


public class EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink
{
    public EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink()
    {
        this.TheJobTitle = new JobTitle() { JobTitleSurrogateKey = Guid.NewGuid(), JobTitleName = "SomeJobTitle:" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") };
    }
    public Guid LinkSurrogateKey { get; set; }
    /* Related Objects */
    public Employee TheEmployee { get; set; }
    public JobTitle TheJobTitle { get; set; }
}


public class Organization
{
    public Organization()
    {
        this.Links = new List<EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink>();
    }

     public int OrganizationSurrogateKey { get; set; }

    public ICollection<EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink> Links { get; set; }
}
```

In my code below, I can compare 2 child-collections and get the results I need (in "matches1".
Here I am using the "SSN" string property to compare and find the overlaps.  And the Console.Write for matches1 works as I expect.

What I don't know how to do is compare the first child collection (org10) to all the children in (allOtherOrgsExceptOrg10 (all the Organizations and all the Links of these Organizations )

The commented out code shows kinda what I'm trying to do, one of my many feeble attempts today.

But basically, match2 would be populated with all the SSN overlaps...but comparing org10 with allOtherOrgsExceptOrg10, all their "Links", and their Employee.SSN's.
org10 overlaps with org20 with "AAA", so match2 would contain "AAA".  and org10 overlaps with org30 with "BBB" so match2 would contain "BBB".

```
            Organization org10 = new Organization();
            org10.OrganizationSurrogateKey = 10;

            Employee e11 = new Employee() { SSN = "AAA", EmployeeUUID = new Guid("AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA") };
            EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink link11 = new EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink();
            link11.TheEmployee = e11;

            org10.Links.Add(link11);

            Employee e12 = new Employee() { SSN = "BBB", EmployeeUUID = new Guid("BBBBBBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBBBBBBBBBB") };
            EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink link12 = new EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink();
            link12.TheEmployee = e12;

            org10.Links.Add(link12);



            Organization org20 = new Organization();
            org20.OrganizationSurrogateKey = 20;

            Employee e21 = new Employee() { SSN = "AAA", EmployeeUUID = new Guid("AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA") };
            EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink link21 = new EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink();
            link21.TheEmployee = e21;

            org20.Links.Add(link21);

            Employee e22 = new Employee() { SSN = "CCC", EmployeeUUID = new Guid("CCCCCCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCCCCCCCCCC") };
            EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink link22 = new EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink();
            link22.TheEmployee = e22;

            org20.Links.Add(link22);



            Organization org30 = new Organization();
            org30.OrganizationSurrogateKey = 30;

            Employee e31 = new Employee() { SSN = "BBB", EmployeeUUID = new Guid("BBBBBBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBBBBBBBBBB") };
            EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink link31 = new EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink();
            link31.TheEmployee = e31;

            org30.Links.Add(link31);

            Employee e32 = new Employee();
            e32.SSN = "ZZZ";
            EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink link32 = new EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink();
            link32.TheEmployee = e32;

            org30.Links.Add(link32);


            IList<Organization> allOtherOrgsExceptOrg10 = new List<Organization>();

            /* Note, I did not add org10 here */
            allOtherOrgsExceptOrg10.Add(org20);
            allOtherOrgsExceptOrg10.Add(org30);


            IEnumerable<EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink> matches1 =
            org10.Links.Where(org10Link => org20.Links.Any(org20Link => org20Link.TheEmployee.SSN.Equals(org10Link.TheEmployee.SSN, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));


            IEnumerable<EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink> matches2 = null;
            //org10.Links.Where(org10Link  =>  ( allOtherOrgs.Where ( anyOtherOrg  => anyOtherOrg.Links.Any(dbSideChild => dbSideChild.TheEmployee.SSN == org10Link.TheEmployee.SSN)) );


            if (null != matches1)
            {
                foreach (EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink link in matches1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("matches1, SSN = {0}", link.TheEmployee.SSN));
                }
            }

            if (null != matches2)
            {
                foreach (EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink link in matches2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("matches2, SSN = {0}", link.TheEmployee.SSN));
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use SelectMany to flatten out the collection and then use it just like you have for matches1

```
IEnumerable<EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink> matches2 =
            org10.Links.Where(
                org10Link =>
                allOtherOrgsExceptOrg10.SelectMany(allOtherOrgs => allOtherOrgs.Links).Any(
                    anyOtherLink =>
                    anyOtherLink.TheEmployee.SSN.Equals(org10Link.TheEmployee.SSN, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
```

The SelectMany will make it seem like one IEnumerable instead of and IEnumerable of an IEnumerable.

Answer (score 1):

```
matches2 =
            allOtherOrgsExceptOrg10.SelectMany(x => x.Links)
                .Where(x => org10.Links.Select(o => o.TheEmployee.SSN).Contains(x.TheEmployee.SSN));
```

You can use the SelectMany on the allOther collection to select all Links over all org's. Then check if any SSN is inside the org10 List.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.100).aspx